# PXE Boot or normal boot

Tags: pxe

How can I find out if system is booted from **PXE** or from **Local HDD** or from **any removable media** ?

I want to write initramfs for a system which will function differently according to its boot method.

Comment: Examine where the root partition is mounted, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the kernel command line (available at /proc/cmdline).

If the PXE vs local HDD (grub, lilo, extlinux) are not already different, then the PXE server could add an extra parameter that is never present in the local HDD boot. Also, the HDD boot-loader could introduce a parameter which would not be present on a removable media bootstrap.

Of course, this would not work if you are trying to detect an intentional unauthorized boot method, because the attacker would simply add the matching boot parameters, or just modify the initrd.